# Python return value without inverted commas

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I have csv file:

shack_imei.csv:

```
shack, imei
F10, "5555"
```

code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("shack_imei.csv", "rb"))
my_dict = dict(reader)


shack = raw_input('Enter Shack:')
print shack
def get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack):
    for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
        if key == shack:
            return value

list = str(get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack))
print list
```

which gives me `"5555"`
But I need this value in a list structure like this:

```
["5555"]
```

I've tried a lot of different methods, and they all end up with extra `'` or`""`

EDIT 1:
new simpler code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("shack_imei.csv", "rb"))
my_dict = dict(reader)
shack = raw_input('Enter Shack:')
imei = my_dict[shack]
print imei
```

"5555"

`list(imei)` gives me `['"5555"']`, I need it to be `["5555"]`

Comment: Accessing the `value` of a certain `key` in a `dict`, use `my_dict[key]` - no need for a separate method iterating over every item in the dict. Also, don't use names like `list` for variables, since this will shadow built in functions.

Comment: `your_list = [str(get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack))] ` if you want your string as an element of a list

Answer (score 0):

You can change your "return" sentence:

```
shack = raw_input('Enter Shack:')
print shack
def get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack):
    for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
        if key == shack:
            return [str(value)]

list = get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack)
print list
```

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: Note that `csv.reader` doesn't do any kind of conversion at all - so the `str(value)` can just be `value`

Comment: Suggestion: don't name a variable `list `

Comment: This still gives me `[' "555" ']`, when i need `["5555"]`

Comment: Same comment as for the original question: `dict` access via `my_dict[key]`.

Comment: @wazzahenry: The extra `' "5555"'` is coming from the `csv.reader`, since it splits only on `,`, thus you get the extra space before 5555.

Comment: fine, but how do I get rid of the `'`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to create a list containing the returned string, which you do with [ ]

```
list = [str(get_imei_from_entered_shack(shack))]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code, which are too long to tackle in comments

## `my_dict`

`my_dict = dict(reader)` works only well if this csv is a collection of keys and values. If there are duplicate keys, this might give some problems

## `get_imei_from_entered_shack`

Why this special method, instead of just asking `my_dict` the correct value. Even if you don't want it to trow an `Exception` when you ask for a `shack` that doesn't exists, you can use the `dict.get(<key>, <default>)` method

```
my_dict(shack, None)
```

does the same as your 4-line method

## list

don't name variables the same as `builtin`s

## list2

if you want a list, you can do `[<value>]` or `list(<value>)` (unless you replaced `list` with your own variable assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = csv.reader(open("shack_imei.csv", "rb"))
my_dict = dict(reader)
shack = raw_input('Enter Shack:')
imei = my_dict[shack]
imei = imei.replace('"',"")

IMEI_LIST =[]
IMEI_LIST.append(imei)
print IMEI_LIST
['5555']
```